# Равносильно ли следующие реализации проверки видимости точки в Яндекс.Картах?

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Есть два способа определить входит ли точка в область видимости. Является ли один шортхендом для другого? Одинаково ли работают?

(Далее object это элемент перебора objectManager.objects.)

1.:

```
objectManager.getObjectState(object.id).isShown;
```

2.:

```
ymaps.util.bounds.containsPoint(
   map.getBounds(),
   object.geometry.coordinates
);
```

Если способы разные, то какой правильнее?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, т.к. `ObjectManager` может скрывать точки на основании [фильтров](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/ObjectManager.html#method_detail__setFilter).